# Change focus between textfields in a prototype tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

Is it possible to make a keyboard accessory input view (as shown in the image) to change the focus between textfields that are inside a dynamics cells?.

I could do it when the textfields are static, but I’m having trouble trying to implement this in a prototype tableview with textfields defined inside of custom cells.

[image]

Comment: Use [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) for this.

Comment: He mentioned that he's using dynamic cells. Can you give us some idea how to make IQKeyboardManager useful in this case, @the4kman?

Comment: Check out [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/issues/497).

Comment: Thanks!!! IQKeyboardManager is every that I need!